# Create grouped lagged indicator in R

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse, dplyr

I am trying to create a grouped new variable in R that is based on the lagged value of a another variable.

My data.frame looks like this:

```
str(parlgov)
tibble [8,623 × 16] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ country_name_short             : chr [1:8623] "AUS" "AUS" "AUS" "AUS" ...
 $ country_name                   : chr [1:8623] "Australia" "Australia" "Australia" "Australia" ...
 $ election_type                  : chr [1:8623] "parliament" "parliament" "parliament" "parliament" ...
 $ election_date                  : Date[1:8623], format: "1901-03-30" "1901-03-30" "1901-03-30" ...
 $ vote_share                     : num [1:8623] 44.4 34.2 19.4 1.4 0.6 29.7 34.4 31 0.5 4.5 ...
 $ seats                          : num [1:8623] 32 26 15 1 1 26 25 23 1 0 ...
 $ seats_total                    : num [1:8623] 75 75 75 75 75 75 75 75 75 75 ...
 $ party_name_short               : chr [1:8623] "PP" "FTP" "ALP" "none" ...
 $ party_name                     : chr [1:8623] "Protectionist Party" "Free Trade Party" "Australian Labor Party" "no party affiliation" ...
 $ party_name_english             : chr [1:8623] "Protectionist Party" "Free Trade Party" "Australian Labor Party" "no party affiliation" ...
 $ left_right                     : num [1:8623] 7.4 6 3.88 NA NA ...
 $ country_id                     : num [1:8623] 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 ...
 $ election_id                    : num [1:8623] 731 731 731 731 731 730 730 730 730 730 ...
 $ previous_parliament_election_id: num [1:8623] NA NA NA NA NA 731 731 731 731 731 ...
 $ previous_cabinet_id            : num [1:8623] NA NA NA NA NA 997 997 997 997 997 ...
 $ party_id                       : num [1:8623] 1898 1938 1253 1396 2299 ...
```

Since the data.frame is too large I am leaving a `dput` of a random sample of rows:

```
dfsample  <- sample_n(parlgov, 100)
dput(dfsample)
structure(list(country_name_short = c("GBR", "LVA", "FRA", "CHE", 
"DNK", "CAN", "PRT", "CYP", "ISR", "SVN", "LUX", "MLT", "AUS", 
"DNK", "ITA", "FIN", "SVK", "LTU", "DEU", "CZE", "FRA", "SVN", 
"DNK", "NLD", "EST", "GBR", "BEL", "CHE", "GRC", "GBR", "AUT", 
"NLD", "ROU", "DNK", "FRA", "LTU", "JPN", "ITA", "NOR", "SVK", 
"FRA", "HRV", "CHE", "ITA", "DEU", "NLD", "ITA", "BEL", "HUN", 
"NZL", "PRT", "AUS", "CZE", "LUX", "FIN", "MLT", "ISR", "GBR", 
"ISL", "ISL", "BGR", "NOR", "ITA", "CZE", "CHE", "GRC", "IRL", 
"DNK", "DNK", "CHE", "ITA", "ROU", "SVN", "BEL", "NZL", "CAN", 
"DNK", "ISR", "ISR", "BEL", "CYP", "FRA", "LUX", "HRV", "FRA", 
"FIN", "NLD", "NOR", "IRL", "ISR", "NOR", "SVN", "LVA", "DNK", 
"ROU", "ISR", "NLD", "DNK", "SVK", "IRL"), country_name = c("United Kingdom", 
"Latvia", "France", "Switzerland", "Denmark", "Canada", "Portugal", 
"Cyprus", "Israel", "Slovenia", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Australia", 
"Denmark", "Italy", "Finland", "Slovakia", "Lithuania", "Germany", 
"Czech Republic", "France", "Slovenia", "Denmark", "Netherlands", 
"Estonia", "United Kingdom", "Belgium", "Switzerland", "Greece", 
"United Kingdom", "Austria", "Netherlands", "Romania", "Denmark", 
"France", "Lithuania", "Japan", "Italy", "Norway", "Slovakia", 
"France", "Croatia", "Switzerland", "Italy", "Germany", "Netherlands", 
"Italy", "Belgium", "Hungary", "New Zealand", "Portugal", "Australia", 
"Czech Republic", "Luxembourg", "Finland", "Malta", "Israel", 
"United Kingdom", "Iceland", "Iceland", "Bulgaria", "Norway", 
"Italy", "Czech Republic", "Switzerland", "Greece", "Ireland", 
"Denmark", "Denmark", "Switzerland", "Italy", "Romania", "Slovenia", 
"Belgium", "New Zealand", "Canada", "Denmark", "Israel", "Israel", 
"Belgium", "Cyprus", "France", "Luxembourg", "Croatia", "France", 
"Finland", "Netherlands", "Norway", "Ireland", "Israel", "Norway", 
"Slovenia", "Latvia", "Denmark", "Romania", "Israel", "Netherlands", 
"Denmark", "Slovakia", "Ireland"), election_type = c("ep", "parliament", 
"ep", "parliament", "parliament", "parliament", "ep", "parliament", 
"parliament", "parliament", "parliament", "parliament", "parliament", 
"parliament", "parliament", "parliament", "parliament", "parliament", 
"parliament", "parliament", "parliament", "parliament", "parliament", 
"ep", "ep", "parliament", "ep", "parliament", "ep", "ep", "parliament", 
"parliament", "ep", "ep", "parliament", "parliament", "parliament", 
"ep", "parliament", "parliament", "parliament", "parliament", 
"parliament", "ep", "parliament", "parliament", "ep", "ep", "parliament", 
"parliament", "ep", "parliament", "parliament", "ep", "parliament", 
"parliament", "parliament", "ep", "parliament", "parliament", 
"parliament", "parliament", "parliament", "parliament", "parliament", 
"parliament", "parliament", "parliament", "parliament", "parliament", 
"ep", "parliament", "parliament", "ep", "parliament", "parliament", 
"parliament", "parliament", "parliament", "ep", "ep", "parliament", 
"parliament", "parliament", "parliament", "ep", "parliament", 
"parliament", "ep", "parliament", "parliament", "parliament", 
"parliament", "parliament", "ep", "parliament", "parliament", 
"parliament", "parliament", "parliament"), election_date = structure(c(18039, 
9404, 7108, 12344, 2602, -14402, 14402, 7808, 5317, 17685, 7108, 
-7059, -18282, 6704, 17594, 3364, 16866, 15627, -18610, 16003, 
8487, 12694, -18147, 18039, 14402, -14826, 7108, -795, 18042, 
14399, 6170, -13399, 14402, 18042, 4189, 9789, 15690, 10755, 
-15417, 15409, 13681, 10959, 5043, 18042, -13570, 7188, 16215, 
16215, 17629, -18278, 16215, -9630, 10397, 12582, -2887, -6815, 
9645, 3447, -2398, 15822, 12959, 17420, -8614, 8192, 18189, 16460, 
11824, -17999, 3582, 2124, 5281, 17146, 12694, 10755, -18278, 
-23800, -15736, 13235, -5273, 8928, 12582, -16657, 15998, 17055, 
-8838, 12582, 13474, 2810, 18040, -1522, -7388, 9810, 11965, 
6459, 13842, 18323, -13399, 7650, 18321, 4710), class = "Date"), 
    vote_share = c(14.1, 1.49, 23.61, 23.3, 3.3, 1.24, 28.41, 
    35.8, 31.9, 1.09, 5.1, 5.99, 42.5, 4.7, 18.76, 1.2, 5.61, 
    7.31, 10.26, 14.91, 1.8, 6.82, 0.9, 12.18, 26.1, 23.44, 21.14, 
    1.4, 1.23, 1.01, 43.1, 1, 4.22, 3.4, 36, 2.2, 5.69, 17.34, 
    36.84, 8.55, 2.47, 1.9, NA, 1.75, 3.26, 0.44, 4.38, 6.69, 
    NA, 9.98, 4.93, 3.5, 8.6, 22.09, 0.3, 35.47, 7.4, 12.6, 28.2, 
    26.7, 5.19, 10.3, 18.93, 5.87, 15.11, 2.46, NA, 34, 3.7, 
    21.1, 1.44, 8.87, 6.27, 9.39, 30.14, 0.34, 20.6, 9.5, 8.2, 
    2.95, 10.79, 9.82, 20.28, 32.18, 23.77, 10.4, 5.89, 4.2, 
    11.37, 0.9, 6.14, 1.15, 9.5, NA, 2.4, 5.98, 21.5, 8.3, NA, 
    39.22), seats = c(10, 0, 22, 52, 6, 2, 7, 20, 41, 0, 1, 1, 
    26, 9, 112, 0, 10, 12, 41, 33, 6, 7, 0, 4, 2, 59, 5, 3, 0, 
    0, 80, 1, 1, 0, 268, 3, 9, 15, 59, 16, 9, 0, 1, 0, 20, 0, 
    3, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 19, 1, 1, 15, 9, 0, 19, 19, 13, 19, 104, 
    14, 29, 0, 12, 51, 6, 46, 1, 30, 6, 2, 19, 1, 30, 12, 10, 
    1, 0, 26, 13, 39, 134, 1, 9, 2, 2, 0, 9, 0, 10, 1, 0, 7, 
    22, 15, 0, 70), seats_total = c(73, 100, 81, 200, 179, 245, 
    22, 56, 120, 90, 60, 40, 75, 179, 630, 200, 150, 141, 423, 
    200, 577, 90, 139, 26, 6, 615, 24, 200, 21, 72, 183, 100, 
    33, 13, 474, 141, 480, 87, 150, 150, 577, 151, 200, 73, 584, 
    150, 73, 21, 199, 80, 21, 75, 200, 6, 200, 40, 120, 81, 60, 
    63, 240, 169, 556, 200, 200, 300, 166, 148, 179, 200, 81, 
    329, 90, 25, 80, 214, 148, 120, 120, 25, 6, 574, 60, 151, 
    522, 14, 150, 155, 11, 120, 150, 90, 100, 179, 35, 120, 100, 
    179, 150, 166), party_name_short = c("Lab", "TPA", "PS", 
    "SP-PS", "RF", "L", "PS", "DISY", "L", "ZS", "KPL", "DAP", 
    "ALP", "CD", "PD", "POP", "S", "TT-LDP", "DNVP", "KSCM", 
    "MP", "SLS", "no-seat", "CDA", "EK", "Lib", "CVP|CD&V", "DG", 
    "LAOS", "NO2EU", "SPO", "CDU", "none", "A", "PS", "LDP", 
    "TPJ", "DS", "DNA", "OLaNO", "droite", "HSU", "one-seat", 
    "S", "BVP", "SP", "NCD", "AGL-Gr", "FKgP", "none", "BE", 
    "LCL", "US", "LSAP", "AS", "PN", "Meretz", "Lib", "F", "Sj", 
    "BNS", "Sp", "PCI", "HSD-SMS", "FDP-PRD", "KIDISO", "none", 
    "V", "VS", "KK/CVP", "DP", "USR", "SNS", "VB", "NZLP", "none", 
    "KF", "Shas", "AhAv", "FN", "EDEK", "PCF", "LSAP", "SPH", 
    "PS", "VIHR", "PVV", "SV", "Green", "no-seat", "FeBo", "SOPS", 
    "LPP", "Jf", "PIN", "YaToMe", "SDAP", "SF", "SPOLU", "FG"
    ), party_name = c("Labour Party", "Tautsaimnieku politisk? apvien?ba", 
    "Parti socialiste", "Sozialdemokratische Partei der Schweiz \x96 Parti Socialiste Suisse", 
    "Retsforbund", "Labour Party", "Partido Socialista", "Dimokratik\xf3s Sinayerm\xf3s", 
    "Likud", "Zeleni Slovenije", "Kommunistesch Partei L\xebtzebuerg", 
    "Democratic Action Party", "Australian Labor Party", "Centrumdemokraterne", 
    "Partito Democratico", "Perustuslaillinen Oikeistopuolue \x96 Konstitutionella h\xf6gerpartiet", 
    "Sie?", "Tvarka ir teisingumas \x96 Liberal? demokrat? partija", 
    "Deutschnationale Volkspartei", "Komunistick\xe1 strana Cech a Moravy", 
    "Parti de la Majorit\xe9 pr\xe9sidentielle", "Slovenska ljudska stranka", 
    "no seat", "Christen Democratisch App\xe8l", "Eesti Keskerakond", 
    "Liberals", "Christelijke Volkspartij | Christen-Democratisch en Vlaams", 
    "Gruppe der Demokraten \x96 Groupe des democrates", "La\xefk\xf3s Orth\xf3doxos Synagerm\xf3s", 
    "NO2EU \x96 Yes to Democracy", "Sozialdemokratische Partei \xd6sterreichs", 
    "Christelijk-Democratische Unie", "no party affiliation", 
    "Alternativet", "Parti socialiste", "Lietuvos demokrat? partija", 
    "Nippon Mirai no T?", "Democratici di Sinistra", "Det norske Arbeiderparti", 
    "Oby?ajn\xed ?udia a nez\xe1visl\xe9 osobnosti", "divers droite", 
    "Hrvatska stranka umirovljenika", "one seat", "Sinistra", 
    "Bayerische Volkspartei", "Socialistiese Partij", "Nuovo Centrodestra | Alternativa Popolare", 
    "Agalev \x96 Groen", "F\xfcggetlen Kisgazda P\xe1rt", "no party affiliation", 
    "Bloco de Esquerda", "Liberal and Country League", "Unie svobody", 
    "L\xebtzebuerger Sozialistesch Aarbechterpartei", "\xc5l\xe4ndsk Samlingin \xe4\xe4nt\xe4 \x96 \xc5l\xe4ndsk Samling", 
    "Partit Nazzjonalista", "Meretz", "Liberals", "Frams\xf3knarflokkurinn", 
    "Sj\xe1lfst\xe6\xf0isflokkurinn", "Balgarski Naroden Suyuz", 
    "Senterpartiet", "Partito Comunista Italiano", "Hnut\xed za samospr\xe1vnou demokracii \x96 Spole?nost pro Moravu a Slezsko", 
    "Freisinnig-Demokratische Partei der Schweiz \x96 Parti Radical-Democratique Suisse", 
    "Kinima Dimokraton Sosialiston", "no party affiliation", 
    "Venstre", "Venstresocialisterne", "Katholische Konservative / Christlichdemokratische Volkspartei \x96 Conservateurs catholiques  /  Parti d\xe9mocrate-chr\xe9tien", 
    "Democrazia Proletaria", "Uniunea Salva?i Rom\xe2nia", "Slovenska nacionalna stranka", 
    "Vlaams Blok", "New Zealand Liberal Party", "no party affiliation", 
    "Konservative", "Shomrei Sfarad", "Ahdut HaAvoda", "Front National", 
    "Kinima Sosialdimokraton EDEK", "Parti communiste fran\xe7aise", 
    "L\xebtzebuerger Sozialistesch Aarbechterpartei", "Socijaldemokratska partija Hrvatske", 
    "Parti socialiste", "Vihre\xe4 Liitto \x96 Gr\xf6na F\xf6rbundet", 
    "Partij voor de Vrijheid", "Sosialistisk Venstreparti", "Green Party  \x96 Comhaontas Glas", 
    "no seat", "Felleslister borgerlige", "Slovenska obrtno podjetni\x9aka stranka", 
    "Latvijas Pirm? partija", "Javna\xf0arflokkurin", "Partidul Ini?iativa Na?ional?", 
    "Yahadut HaTora HaMeuhedet", "Sociaal Democratische Arbeiders Partij", 
    "Socialistisk Folkeparti", "SPOLU \x96 ob?ianska demokracia", 
    "Fine Gael"), party_name_english = c("Labour", "Political Union of Economists", 
    "Socialist Party", "Social Democratic Party of Switzerland", 
    "Justice Party", "Labour Party", "Socialist Party", "Democratic Rally", 
    "The Consolidation", "Greens of Slovenia", "Communist Party of Luxembourg", 
    "Democratic Action Party", "Australian Labor Party", "Centre Democrats", 
    "Democratic Party", "Constitutional People's Party", "Network", 
    "Order and Justice -- Liberal Democratic Party", "German National People's Party", 
    "Communist Party of Bohemia and Moravia", "Party of Presidential Majority", 
    "Slovenian People's Party", "no seat", "Christian Democratic Appeal", 
    "Estonian Centre Party", "Liberals", "Flemish Christian Peoples Party | Christian Democrats & Flemish", 
    "Democratic Group", "Popular Orthodox Rally", "NO2EU -- Yes to Democracy", 
    "Social Democratic Party of Austria", "Christian Democratic Union", 
    "no party affiliation", "The Alternative", "Socialist Party", 
    "Lithuanian Democratic Party", "Tomorrow Party of Japan", 
    "Democrats of the Left", "Norwegian Labour Party", "Ordinary People and Independent", 
    "other right", "Croatian Party of Pensioners", "one seat", 
    "Left", "Bavarian People's Party", "Socialist Party", "New Centre-Right | Popular Alternative", 
    "Agalev -- Green", "Independent Small Holders Party", "no party affiliation", 
    "Bloc of the Left", "Liberal and Country League", "Freedom Union", 
    "Luxembourg Socialist Workers' Party", "Aland Coalition", 
    "Nationalist Party", "Energy", "Liberals", "Progressive Party", 
    "Independence Party", "Bulgarian People's Union", "Centre Party", 
    "Communist Party", "Movement for Self-Governing Democracy -- Society for Moravia and Silesia", 
    "Radical Democratic Party", "Movement of Democratic Socialists", 
    "no party affiliation", "Liberal Party", "Left Socialists", 
    "Catholic Conservative / Christian Democratic Peoples Party", 
    "Proletarian Democracy", "Save Romania Union", "Slovenian National Party", 
    "Flemish Block", "New Zealand Liberal Party", "no party affiliation", 
    "Conservatives", "Sfarad's guards of the Torah", "Labour Unity", 
    "National Front", "Movement for Social Democracy EDEK", "French Communist Party", 
    "Luxembourg Socialist Workers' Party", "Social Democratic Party of Croatia", 
    "Socialist Party", "Green League", "Party for Freedom", "Socialist Left Party", 
    "Green Party", "no seat", "Electoral lists Conservatives", 
    "Slovenian Craftsmen and Entreprenerial Party", "Latvia's First Party", 
    "Social Democratic Party (Faroe Islands)", "National Initiative Party", 
    "United Torah Judaism", "Social Democratic Workers' Party", 
    "Socialist Peoples Party", "TOGETHER -- Civic Democracy", 
    "Fine Gael (Familiy of the Irish)"), left_right = c(4.3562, 
    6, 3.2493, 1.8319, 6, 3.3, 4.0492, 8.6842, 6.6788, 2.5, 1.3, 
    7.4, 3.8833, 5.5609, 2.6216, 7.4, 7.4, 5.2955, 8.8, 0.7498, 
    1.3, 6.6953, NA, 5.9376, 3.9562, 4.2875, 5.7667, 3.3, 9.11, 
    1.3, 3.7293, 6.2, NA, 2.5, 3.2493, 5.8333, 2.5, 2.6277, 3.3706, 
    7.4, 7.6583, NA, NA, 1.3, 6.2, 1.3682, 7.4, 2.5762, 9.0186, 
    NA, 1.6425, 3.3, 7.2204, 3.2895, NA, 5.7143, 1.7786, 4.2875, 
    5.0365, 7.4854, 5.8, 4.6565, 1.6, NA, 6.3249, 3.3, NA, 7.292, 
    0.8, 4.7288, 0.5, 6, 4.7941, 9.6622, 6, NA, 7.2186, 7.0417, 
    3.3, 9.655, 3.2895, 1.3741, 3.2895, 3.2456, 3.2493, 3.6465, 
    8.8, 1.5839, 2.435, NA, 7.4, 6, 6.3377, 3.3, 7.4, 6.9396, 
    3.3, 2.1347, 6, 6.4372), country_id = c(44, 55, 43, 40, 21, 
    29, 63, 51, 34, 60, 7, 72, 33, 21, 26, 67, 1, 15, 54, 68, 
    43, 60, 21, 8, 75, 44, 64, 40, 41, 44, 59, 8, 23, 21, 43, 
    15, 5, 26, 9, 1, 43, 62, 40, 26, 54, 8, 26, 64, 39, 11, 63, 
    33, 68, 7, 67, 72, 34, 44, 56, 56, 10, 9, 26, 68, 40, 41, 
    37, 21, 21, 40, 26, 23, 60, 64, 11, 29, 21, 34, 34, 64, 51, 
    43, 7, 62, 43, 67, 8, 9, 37, 34, 9, 60, 55, 21, 23, 34, 8, 
    21, 1, 37), election_id = c(1051, 534, 360, 206, 409, 858, 
    5, 342, 714, 1025, 526, 135, 723, 387, 1024, 84, 1003, 786, 
    1031, 805, 664, 80, 893, 1052, 395, 909, 553, 373, 1060, 
    410, 235, 941, 229, 1049, 20, 566, 788, 363, 867, 781, 171, 
    797, 631, 1053, 1039, 627, 834, 832, 1023, 954, 838, 737, 
    27, 593, 354, 244, 717, 37, 379, 798, 618, 1017, 503, 39, 
    1083, 851, 408, 894, 242, 371, 458, 1015, 80, 624, 954, 884, 
    896, 720, 706, 536, 397, 991, 803, 1007, 471, 198, 578, 499, 
    1061, 709, 478, 338, 260, 226, 676, 1090, 941, 157, 1089, 
    307), previous_parliament_election_id = c(1013, 564, 643, 
    427, 464, 859, 210, 127, 713, 817, 183, 550, 750, 226, 789, 
    98, 781, 646, NA, 599, 643, 525, 892, 1012, 83, 908, 191, 
    108, 992, 233, 456, 940, 319, 976, 496, 439, 327, 551, 951, 
    524, 403, NA, 435, 1024, 1038, 62, 789, 486, 814, 953, 702, 
    738, 301, 299, 616, 135, 716, 243, 320, 36, 681, 801, NA, 
    63, 995, 784, 316, 1000, 409, 176, 617, 787, 525, 332, 953, 
    883, 895, 719, 705, 418, 339, 990, 172, 1001, 983, 253, 335, 
    523, 1002, 708, 220, 382, 615, 597, 165, 1079, 940, 387, 
    1003, 228), previous_cabinet_id = c(1507, 201, 712, 198, 
    50, 1167, 169, 784, 1114, 1144, 175, 1470, 1010, 837, 1501, 
    492, 1027, 1026, NA, 1062, 199, 292, 1481, 1530, 902, 1291, 
    457, 513, 1593, 119, 828, 1258, 599, 1497, 1148, 91, 969, 
    214, 1231, 982, 807, NA, 723, 1532, 1580, 550, 1079, 987, 
    1104, 1320, 917, 995, 76, 196, 598, 1471, 960, 273, 331, 
    651, 575, 1065, NA, 262, 1212, 1060, 126, 1249, 824, 79, 
    334, 1197, 292, 95, 1320, 1466, 1246, 1129, 928, 624, 342, 
    1354, 1063, 1408, 329, 759, 65, 520, 1511, 935, 58, 562, 
    23, 195, 118, 1613, 1258, 57, 1529, 54), party_id = c(1556, 
    278, 1539, 35, 1606, 2427, 725, 1575, 678, 1619, 151, 816, 
    1253, 1324, 382, 1389, 2624, 1421, 2692, 1173, 2260, 16, 
    2058, 235, 1137, 659, 723, 886, 1179, 2147, 973, 2542, 761, 
    2567, 1539, 1144, 2785, 809, 104, 1759, 285, 2134, 2303, 
    465, 2697, 357, 2268, 1594, 870, 1262, 557, 1919, 688, 701, 
    66, 984, 1419, 659, 1455, 1342, 1375, 702, 1088, 19, 26, 
    2407, 30, 1605, 189, 531, 1424, 2646, 981, 993, 2469, 1189, 
    590, 788, 1343, 171, 945, 686, 701, 1493, 1539, 1062, 1501, 
    81, 1573, 2308, 2194, 2275, 1043, 1894, 1589, 1303, 1451, 
    1644, 2752, 1393)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(country_name_short = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), country_name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), election_type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), election_date = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_date", 
    "collector")), vote_share = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), seats = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), seats_total = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), party_name_short = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), party_name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), party_name_english = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), left_right = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), country_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), election_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), previous_parliament_election_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), previous_cabinet_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), party_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

What I want to do is to have a variable that is equal to the lagged value of `election_date` where `election_type == "ep"` for each group of `country_id` and `election_id`.

I tried a lot of different things like this:

```
parlgov%>%
  filter(election_type %in% c("ep", "parliament"))%>%
  group_by(country_id, election_type)%>%
  arrange(election_date)%>%
  mutate(prev_election_ep = lag(election_date))
```

But what I get out most times is the lag value for each row, and not each group of  `country_id` and `election_id`.

Basically, what I want is a new variable in which each group of  `country_id` and `election_id` which takes the value of the last `election_type == "ep"` has for `election_date`. Something like this (dummy data):

```
country_name_short country_id election_type election_date prev_election_ep
1                 CZE          5 parliamentary    1999-03-30             <NA>
2                 CZE          5            ep    2000-03-10             <NA>
3                 CZE          5 parliamentary    2004-03-12       2000-03-10
4                 CZE          5            ep    2005-05-01       2000-03-10
5                 CZE          5 parliamentary    2006-06-03       2005-05-01
6                 DNK         10 parliamentary    2000-03-10       2000-03-10
7                 DNK         10            ep    2000-03-10             <NA>
8                 DNK         10 parliamentary    2005-03-02       2000-03-10
9                 DNK         10 parliamentary    2005-05-01       2000-03-10
10                DNK         10            ep    2009-09-10       2000-03-10
11                ESP         55 parliamentary    1982-03-30             <NA>
12                ESP         55            ep    1985-05-10             <NA>
13                ESP         55 parliamentary    1989-09-31       1985-05-10
14                ESP         55            ep    1990-02-12       1985-05-10
15                ESP         55 parliamentary    1991-04-20       1990-02-12
```

Comment: In addition to your written goal, could you provide an example dataframe of the result you have in mind?

Comment: You can probably remove columns which are not related to the questions, share `dput` of 20-25 rows and show expected output for it. It is not exactly clear from your description what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Added an example of what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this function

```
last_where <- function(x, cond) {
  x[vapply(seq_along(x), function(x, p) {
    out <- tail(which(x > p), 1L)
    if (length(out) < 1L) NA_integer_ else p[[out]]
  }, integer(1L), which(cond))]
}
```

Then this pipeline gets you the desired output

```
parlgov %>% 
  group_by(country_id, election_id) %>% 
  arrange(election_date, election_type, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(prev_elecion_ep = last_where(election_date, election_type == "ep"))
```

Test with your sample data

```
> df %>% 
+     group_by(country_id) %>% 
+     arrange(election_date, election_type, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
+     mutate(prev_elecion_ep1 = last_where(election_date, election_type == "ep"))

   country_name_short country_id election_type election_date prev_election_ep prev_elecion_ep1
   <chr>                   <dbl> <chr>         <date>        <chr>            <date>         
 1 CZE                         5 parliamentary 1999-03-30    <NA>             NA             
 2 CZE                         5 ep            2000-03-10    <NA>             NA             
 3 CZE                         5 parliamentary 2004-03-12    2000-03-10       2000-03-10     
 4 CZE                         5 ep            2005-05-01    2000-03-10       2000-03-10     
 5 CZE                         5 parliamentary 2006-06-03    2005-05-01       2005-05-01     
 6 DNK                        10 ep            2000-03-10    <NA>             NA             
 7 DNK                        10 parliamentary 2000-03-10    2000-03-10       2000-03-10     
 8 DNK                        10 parliamentary 2005-03-02    2000-03-10       2000-03-10     
 9 DNK                        10 parliamentary 2005-05-01    2000-03-10       2000-03-10     
10 DNK                        10 ep            2009-09-10    2000-03-10       2000-03-10     
11 ESP                        55 parliamentary 1982-03-30    <NA>             NA             
12 ESP                        55 ep            1985-05-10    <NA>             NA             
13 ESP                        55 ep            1990-02-12    1985-05-10       1985-05-10     
14 ESP                        55 parliamentary 1991-04-20    1990-02-12       1990-02-12     
15 ESP                        55 parliamentary NA            1985-05-10       1990-02-12
```

Comment: Thanks! It is not quite working from me however. It only works for those rows where elction_type == ep, and not where election_type == "parlamentary", I can't really figure out why. I also updated another version of the dput with only a subsample of the columns

Comment: It's not working likely because you `group_by(country_id, election_type)`. Please do not use `election_type` as a grouping variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this  :

```
library(dplyr)

dfsample <- dfsample %>% 
              arrange(country_name, election_date) %>%
              mutate(grp = cumsum(election_type == 'ep'))

dfsample %>%
  group_by(country_name, grp) %>%
  summarise(prev_election_ep = election_date[election_type == 'ep']) %>%
  mutate(prev_election_ep = lag(prev_election_ep)) %>%
  left_join(dfsample, by = c('country_name', 'grp'))
```

We do not have sufficient data to test this but the logic here is to create a temporary `grp` column for every `ep` value in the data. For the group we get the `election_date` where `election_type = 'ep'` and use `lag` to shift the value one step behind and join the data to original dataframe.

Comment: Thanks! However, I am only getting NAs for prev_election_ep. I added a new dput with a selection of columns, as you suggested. Hopefully it helps

Comment: It would be helpful if you don't give us random rows which have no connection between each other. Instead provide rows for one/two country so that we can make sure that the results are accurate. I don't know how we would verify our answer if you just give us random rows. Also as I mentioned in my comment earlier remove the columns which are not important for your question. I don't see why we need data for `vote_share`, `seats`, `seats_total`, `party_name_short`, `party_name_english`, `left_right` and so many other columns. Make it easy for others to help you.